# Is there a maximum allowed number of Frame Buffer Objects?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

Looking to create a program that will probably use an unnecessary number of FBOs, is there an upper limit on how many can be created in a single instance?

Comment: Just object names via `glGenFramebuffers()`?  Or fully-renderbuffer-populated FBOs?

Comment: I'm using depth-textures rather than renderbuffers, but yeah, as fully populated as it gets I assume.

Comment: @jhauberg, that question asks about the maximum size for a single framebuffer, I want to have multiple different framebuffers

Comment: Why would you make a program that has an "unnecessary number" of *anything*?

Comment: I'm sorry; you're right (i've deleted the comment). But the answer is basically the same. There's no specification for a maximum- so you're likely just limited by available ram/vram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With thanks going to @jhauberg on his clarification, it would seem that there is technically no upper limit as such, only a limit based on available hardware.